# Closing a dropdown in React-Native on the next press

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have a `ScrollView` which contains multiple `View` components as children. Every child can have a dropdown.

Opening the dropdown on a button press works as it should.

Closing the dropdown on the same button or when something inside the dropdown is pressed works too.

Now I gave this a user and they just opened dropdowns over dropdowns without choosing anything or bothering to close the opened dropdowns.

**Is there a way to set an event handler for the next press on the screen after a dropdown was opened so the dropdown closes** if the user wants to do something different?

---

#### Edit

This is kinda my implementation:

```
const App = () =>
  <View>
    ...
    <List items={["one", "two", "three"]}/>
    ...
  </View>

const List = props =>
  <ScrollView>
    {props.items.map(i => <ListItem name={i} key={i}/>)}
  </ScrollView>


class ListItem extends React.Component {
  state = { showDropdown: false};
  
  handleDropdown = () =>
    this.setState(state =>
      ({showDropdown: !state.showDropdown})
    );

  render() {
    return <View>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.handleDropdown}>
        <Text>{this.props.name}</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      {this.state.showDropdown &&
        <Dropdown>
          <DropdownItem onPress={this.handleDropdown}/>
        </Dropdown>
      }
    </View> 
  }
}
```

The dropdown closes when I click on an `ListItem` again or when I click on a `DropdownItem`.

But I also want it to close, when I click somewhere else on the screen, outside of the `List` component and its children.

Comment: What kind of Dropdown component are you using? As far as I know, there is no Dropdown component in React Native.

Comment: wrote one myself.

Comment: In that case the solution probably depends on the implementation :)

Comment: I added an example

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution.

I added a `PanResponder` to my my apps root `View` and used this config:

```js
const handlers = []
const addHandler = handler => handlers.push(handler);
const handleNextPress = (event, state) => handlers.forEach(h => h(event, state));

this.panResponder = PanResponder.create({
  onStartShouldSetPanResponder: () => true,
  onStartShouldSetPanResponderCapture: (event, state) =>
    handleNextPress(event, state)
});

// somewhere else in the app
addHandler(this.closeMyDropdown);
```

The `onStartShouldSetPanResponderCapture` method is called every time a touch happens to check if the touch event should be captured. If it returns a falsy value the event isn't captured and hits the touchable components.

This method allows to sneak in handlers that can do things before the event hits the touchable components of the app or use a timeout to let things happen after the touchable components have reacted to the event.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, you'll want to make the dropdown a controlled component, with a prop that controls whether the dropdown is shown or not, and a callback the component calls when it's tapped.

You can then keep the active dropdown id in the parent component state, and when that is changed, all dropdowns should rerender

Something like:

```js
class List extends Component {
    state = {
        openDrowdownId: null
    }

    openDropDown = id => {
        this.setState({ openDropDownId: id });
    }

    closeDropDown = () => {
        this.setState({ openDropDownId: null });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <ScrollView>
                {this.props.items.map(item => (
                    <View key={item.id}>
                        <Dropdown 
                            isOpen={this.state.openDropDownId === item.id} 
                            open={() => this.openDropDown(item.id)}
                        />
                    </View>
                ))}
            </ScrollView>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: I want the dropdown to close if I touch the screen anywhere, even outside of the dropdown.

Answer (score -1):

What you can do is to set a ref on the dropdown like 
`ref="dropdown"` 
and on the button press

```js
onPress={() => this.refs.dropdown.blur(); }
```

This is like define an id and on button click to tell that this is is going to blur